# TCP IP: Is it possible to read what TCP/UDP data a program is sending remotely?

Tags: tcp, udp

I want to find out how a game client is connecting to a game server. So, I've been using some sniffer programs (MS Resource Monitor, Wireshark, TCPView, and SmartSniff) to find the IP addresses and data sent to the remote computers.

The programs return a large chunk of text that I only assume is standard format for TCP/UDP data. How can I convert this into a readable form? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sniffers, as you may already know, only track the destination address, protocols used, size of packets etc. They don't actually provide info about the data encapsulated inside.

This site will help you with tools for [Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools)

Edit: go for this, it might help you;

[wireshark how to decrypt](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Packet sniffers usually show/record the payload as well as the packet headers.

Answer (score 3):

"Readable" in terms of a packet's payload is relative.  Wireshark will show you the payload of a packet, but it won't always be clear what the data means.  HTTP traffic is easily readable in its raw form, but more sophisticated applications usually use encoded and/or compressed data that only makes sense to the application and server.

I know Wireshark will parse the packets so you can easily tell apart the different parts of the packet and can switch between hex, binary, and text representations of the data, but those don't help if the data isn't meant to be easily readable.