# How to read TCP packet?

Tags: tcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TCP IP: Is it possible to read what TCP/UDP data a program is sending remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168577/tcp-ip-is-it-possible-to-read-what-tcp-udp-data-a-program-is-sending-remotely)

I want to read a packet I've captured with Wireshark. The packet contains data, 133 bytes in length. It is not encrypted. Yet, the HEX form of the data decodes in Wireshark as a string of mostly unintelligible gibberish.

Is there any way to read this data in human-readable form? I'm just trying to figure out how a game client works, that's all.

Comment: How is this any different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168577/tcp-ip-is-it-possible-to-read-what-tcp-udp-data-a-program-is-sending-remotely)?

Comment: Maybe it does not send human readable data? Maybe it sends objects or something else in non-ascii

Comment: Reverse engineering is an art and a skill. There's no step-by-step manual for this. And there's *certainly* no magic program you can run to just tell you what the data means. It's only unintelligible because you don't *understand* it.

Comment: Why should it look like anything other than apparently unintelligible gibberish?

Comment: Wireshark comes with an amazing library of packet disectors. If Wireshark doesn't know what the data means, then that means someone has yet to RE the protocol (or look at published specs) and write a disector. Are you up to the challenge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to know the format to convert it into human-readable form. It's like a book written in Chinese -- if you don't know Chinese, it's going to look like unintelligible gibberish. But it makes perfect sense to anyone who does know Chinese.

Figuring out the format from just the data is as difficult as learning Chinese just from a book written in Chinese. It can be done, but it's a highly-specialized art.

For example, you can try not moving and seeing which numbers stay the same. Then move, and see which numbers change. That might clue you in to where the position information is. However, the entire packet might be scrambled with a pseudo-random sequence, in which case, it will be nearly impossible without reverse-engineering the software.